# Correct word order with "however"

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Which of the following three is correct?

> 1. When parents relate to a child, they do a lot of the work, figuring out what the child needs and then accommodating those needs.
>      This is not, however, the case when two children are interacting.
> 2. [...] This is, however, not the case when two children are interacting.
> 3. [...] However, this is not the case when two children are interacting.

Comment: The word _means_ the same in each case; the differences are only in writing style. In my opinion the third option is the easiest to understand.

Comment: You missed "This, however, is not the case when" and "This is not the case, however, when".